# Are Tacos Delicious? What happens if I eat 7,460 of them?

Tags: achievements, the-secret-world

[Satan gave me a taco once. It made me mighty sick.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-XuMvxi-vc) So naturally, I was suspicious when I met a rather terrifyingly friendly demon-looking-creature in the markets of London who was all too happy to sell me a Taco.

Are there any ill effects, or even, much as it would shock me, beneficial ones to eating these Demon-Tacos? Additionally, there is an achievement, **Tex-Mex T. Rex** for eating **7,460** of these Tacos. Is there any reward or additional benefit conferred along with this achievement? Or is the only reward the smug, satisfaction of having eaten 7,460 tacos, smilingly served up by the servants of Satan himself?

Comment: Yet another one of those questions where you look at the title and go, Huh!?

Comment: Only thing to say. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FK_Zdsy10hQ

Comment: Do you get a poison cloud aura on getting the achievement, a la Ghom in Diablo 3?

Comment: There's now a clothing reward for the achievement - edited my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tacos speed up your out-of-combat health regeneration, but beyond that there are no other effects known at the current time.  (The health regeneration bonus is actually pretty noticeable, even considering how quickly you regen in this game).

You can disassemble them into nachos, but there appears to be no use for those right now.

And of course they're delicious!

EDIT: [Apparently this achievement just rewards a paltry amount of XP and nothing else.](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?p=1214711)

DOUBLEEDIT: As of issue #2:

```
The coveted Taco Hat is now available if you have consumed 7460 tacos or more in-game.
```

Comment: Naturally, I reserve the right to change this if new info comes to light...but I've probably gone through a dozen so far and haven't noticed anything odd.

Comment: And anything known about the achievement?

Comment: I don't think anybody's gotten it yet (I actually checked up on this the other night because I was curious as well).  It wouldn't surprise me if there's a clothing reward for it, but we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT TACO HAT

Comment: I *desperately* hope it's a Turd Ferguson hat.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz  http://s268.photobucket.com/albums/jj2/thirdup_photos/?action=view&current=taco.jpg

Comment: you ought to include the photo of the TACO HAT in your answer rather than burying it in the comments.

Comment: It's hideous.  I refuse to sully my answer with it on principle.  I AM SO DISAPPOINTED.