# Do I have to go to London if I want to look cool? Or can I buy cosmetic clothing anywhere else?

Tags: the-secret-world

I'm playing as a member of the Illuminati, and I've noticed that New York is... well, there's a lot of things wrong with New York but among those things is a distinct lack of *shopping* opportunities.

In London I can [buy tacos from a horrific monster](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75908/are-tacos-delicious-what-happens-if-i-eat-7-460-of-them), securely store my things in a bank vault, and even interact with the outside world by the modern miracle that is a 'postal service'.

Most importantly though, in London, I can hob-nob with the fashionable set, and buy all manner of new duds for my conspiracy-unraveling Magic Gumshoe. After all, if the world is coming to an end, I might as well try to stop it *in style*, right?

However London is big, and inconvenient, and full of Templars (who smell funny).

Can I get that stuff that's being sold in London (or other equally stylish stuff) anywhere else?

Is there a clothing vendor I just haven't found somewhere in New York or Seoul, or is London just inexplicably *better* than the other two faction capitals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have to go to London to buy your stuff. London is set as main social hub and there are no plans to change this.

### Update 1.1

This patch added a pair of clothing vendors to Seoul.

Answer (score 3):

There are currently no cosmetic vendors in any other location in the game, and there have been no solid comments from the developers about adding any.  Many of these items *are* available in the cash shop for Funcom credits, though.  Some of them seem to be exclusive to in-game.

The only other method, at present, of getting cosmetic items is through mission and achievement completion...and I'd argue most of those are *not* equally stylish.

Answer (score 1):

Funcom are adding a tattooist in Seoul - the store will be called Execution which is currently located in London but will be moving to Seoul.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is specifically about clothes.