# Are Nachos Nutritious and/or Tasty?

Tags: the-secret-world

So, I've [asked about Tacos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75908/are-tacos-delicious-what-happens-if-i-eat-7-460-of-them). I know they are a flavorful and beneficial out of combat snack. I still don't know what happens to people who eat 7500 of them, but it's a start.

And then I see this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcmxJ.png]

It's Taco's younger brother! Nacho!

Acquired by disassembling a Taco, I need to know: Are Nachos anywhere near as delicious as Tacos? Or are they a waste of time?

Comment: Doh, I knew I forgot something trivial when I answered that other question! They do indeed break down into nachos. >.>  Also I've actually updated my answer over there, we *do* know what happens when you get the achievement.  (As far as nachos, I have no idea.)

Comment: Not sure, they give a buff that looks very similar to Tacos though.

Comment: Upvote for question. Of course nachos are tasty, but you must apply cheese to boost the deliciousness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Tacos, Nachos are instant cast. However, they provide substantially less healing.

They're arguably the better choice if you're running 2k HP/full DPS gear.

Answer (score 3):

[This thread indicates](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?p=1319843) that Nachos have the same effects as Tacos - both will give you an additional heal for 700 health per tick out of combat, effectively increasing your out of combat health regeneration and reducing downtime between periods of combat.

Unlike Tacos, Nachos have no associated achievement for eating 7460 of them, and only stack in 10s, rather than 100s.